# JQuery mobile want to wipe data when back button pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

On a HTML page (form.html) with HTML form elements in it, when user tap a `#search` button I want to change to another page (result.html) programmatically. That next page just try to print out all the inputs values.

On form.html I have the following. I use data to carry the data to the second page. `#pageHome` is the ID of the `<div data-role="page">` on the first page.

```
$(document).on("pageinit","#pageHome", function(){
  $('#search').on('tap', function(event) {
    $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer('change', 'result.html',
      {
        data : {
          'searchtext' : $('#searchtext').val(),
          'searchtype' : $('#searchtype').val(),
          'display' : $('input[name=display]:checked').val()
        }
      });
    )
  }
}
```

Also on form.html, I attempt to print the values from the form inputs:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', "#pageResult", function () {
    var parameters = $(this).data("url").split("?")[1].split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++) {
      var keyval = parameters[i].split('=')
      var key = keyval[0],
          val = keyval[1];
      $('.ui-content').append('<h3>' + key + ' ' + val + '</h3>');
    }
 }
```

The element `#pageResult` is the `<div data-role="page">` of the second html.

Two questions:

(1) The second code I had to put in form.html, not result.html which does not seem to work, why not?

(2) When I press the back button (either via the browser or the back button of the result.html), the stuff I appended to the ui-content of the `#pageResult` still exists. In fact it appears to be under #pageHome. How to make it disappear?

**EDIT**
form.html contains just one "page", `#pageHome`, it contains a few inputs, `#searchtext`, `#searchtype`, and a radio buttons with name `display`.
result.html contains just one "page", `#pageResult`.

I'm just testing form inputs. All I want to do is to print the input values directly on the result.html page. The main problem is, when I go back to home.html by pressing the back button, the HTML tags I posted to result.html via JQuery persists.

**EDIT 2**
Answer to question #1 was made more clear to me by Omar in the chat. So, only `<head>` in the first HTML page (the landing page) is loaded. So that's where all scripts should go. Other `<head>s` in external pages are not loaded. Saying styles and codes need to go into other page was just in case user refreshes the page via the browser controls, when everything gets reloaded again.

Comment: form.html is your landing page? It's a bit confusing now. Please clarify what are form.html and result.html are and pages they contain.

Comment: @Omar I made an edit. Does it clarify?

Comment: So you want to reset both form and elements printed in result.html?

Comment: Or maybe I should post the whole pages?

Comment: I thought when I press the "back" button, I should already be back to `#pageHome`, and I should not see anything in `#pageResult`, whether it disappear or not from `#pageResult` should not matter. The thing is, I still see stuff I posted to #pageResult when I hit the back button.

Comment: In fact, after I hit the back button, things I posted to #pageResult actually end up in #pageHome.

Comment: remove the page from the DOM when you click the back button.  $('#pageResult').remove();

Comment: @Tasos external pages are removed by default except for landing page (home page) or in this case form.html.

Comment: @omar ok. never used other Html pages, always multipage templates. what happens if you remove the #pageHome would it reload the page again and solve the Ops issue with displaying the data?

Comment: @Tasos removing landing page will result in having no page in DOM.

Comment: @Omar but he can reload it by, window.location = "form.html"; -- that would surely clear the data issue

Comment: @Tasos it's possible too, but will lose animated transition on navigating back.

Comment: @omar the OP wont notice it. :)))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66312/discussion-between-omar-and-tasos).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using *Single Page Model* only landing page "form.html" is cached and other *external pages* are removed from DOM once you navigate off them. In that case, you don't have to worry to *refresh* results.html because it will be loaded again.

To reset form elements in form.html, wrap element in `form` tag and call `$("#formID")[0].reset()` anytime you want. For example, you can reset it before showing form.html.

```
$(document).on("pagecontainerbeforeshow", function (e, data) {
  if ( data.toPage[0].id == "pageHome" ) {
    $("form", data.toPage)[0].reset();
  }
});
```

As for the second issue, you are selecting `.ui-content` but it is present in DOM twice, in form.html and result.html, so you have to be specific.

```
$(document).on('pagecontainerbeforeshow', function (e, data) {
  if ( data.toPage[0].id == "pageResult" ) {
    var parameters = data.toPage.data("url").split("?")[1].split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++) {
      var keyval = parameters[i].split('=')
      var key = keyval[0],
          val = keyval[1];
      $('.ui-content', data.toPage).append('<h3>' + key + ' ' + val + '</h3>'); /* find content div inside page that received beforeshow event (data.toPage) */
    }
  }
});
```

> **[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/jz0Z1OoCiHg6GuZ0LEdX?p=preview)**

Comment: So, I did type page id `#pageResult` into this `$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', "#pageResult", function () { ...}) `. That doesn't select just that one `.ui-content` in `#pageHome` of the form.html?

Comment: @huggie note that as of 1.4 all page events have changed into [pagecontainer events](http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/jquery-mobile-page-events/) either way, you always have to be specific. `$(".ui-content")` refers to first content div in DOM while `$(".ui-content", this)` or `$(this).find(".ui-content")`, etc. will target that selector in that specific page.

Comment: @huggie btw, `toPage` was added to all pagecontainer events in jQM 1.4.2. Hence I recommend using jQM 1.4.5 to be in the safe side.

Comment: Alright, at least changing into your code works wonderfully. Thanks. BTW, as to my first question in the original post. Do you have an explanation for that? (not required for bounty). Also can you clarify what a single page model is? Apparently it doesn't mean "one html file". So for JQuery mobile that isn't the only model?

Comment: @huggie you mean first point? All libraries/style sheets/js code should be placed in head of all html files. SPM: each page in a separate html file. MPM: all page divs in one html file. You're welcome :) don't hestiate to ask for further details upon this topic.

Comment: I got SPM and MPM reversed then. Thanks for pointing it out. After some trial and error, I noticed that just by modifying `$('.ui-content')` to `$('.ui-content', data.toPage)` solved the problem. 
As for my first question, when I originally put the code `$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', "#pageResult", function () {...}` in the head of `result.html` it doesn't work at all. Why is that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66313/discussion-between-omar-and-huggie).

Answer (score 0):

well its not a direct answer to your question, but why you don't either use localstorage to temporary save your values?

You can use it like

```
localStorage.searchtext = $('#searchtext').val();
localStorage.searchtype = $('#searchtype').val();
localStorage.display = $('input[name=display]:checked').val();
```

Also it would be stored as long is you want, and if you go to the next page or back from it.... Even if the user quits your app it will remain...

When you want to delete data, (what not would be necessary) you can just do it like

```
localStorage.searchtext = null;
localStorage.searchtype = null;
localStorage.display = null;
```

Thats a very easy and handy usage.

Comment: Well, I know about local storage. It just seems like a "global" to me when I only want something transitory. Also, I don't think the problem is related to storage per se, it's the HTML that I manually edited in JQuery doesn't disappear when back button is pressed.